# Why does python have os.path.curdir

Tags: python

`os.path.curdir` returns '.' which is totally truthful and totally worthless.  To get anything useful from it, you have to wrap it with `os.path.abspath(os.path.curdir)`

Why include a useless variable in the os.path module?  Why not have os.path.curdir be a function that does the os.path.abspath for you?

Is there some historic reason for `os.path.curdir` to exist?

Maybe useless is a bit harsh, but not very useful seems weak to describe this.
[image]

Comment: You want `os.getcwd()` instead of `os.path.abspath(os.path.curdir)`.

Comment: One can use it to simplify output of codes like `for (root,dirs,files) in os.walk(os.curdir):
`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It is a constant, just like `os.path.sep`.

Platforms other than POSIX and Windows could use a different value to denote the 'current directory'. On Risc OS it's `@` for example, on the old Macintosh OS it's `:`.

The value is used throughout the standard library to remain platform agnostic.

Use [`os.getcwd()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getcwd) instead; `os.path.abspath()` uses that function under the hood to turn `os.path.curdir` into the current working directory anyway. Here is the POSIX implementation of `abspath()`:

```
def abspath(path):
    """Return an absolute path."""
    if not isabs(path):
        if isinstance(path, _unicode):
            cwd = os.getcwdu()
        else:
            cwd = os.getcwd()
        path = join(cwd, path)
    return normpath(path)
```

Comment: Yea, I had forgotten that some OS's don't have '.' as curdir.  Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

It's just a constant, platform-dependent value.  From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.curdir) (which are worth reading):

> The constant string used by the operating system to refer to the current directory. This is `'.'` for Windows and POSIX. Also available via `os.path`.

You might consider using [`os.getcwd()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getcwd) instead.

Answer (score 9):

The value of `os.path.curdir` is `"."` on Linux, Windows, and OS X.  It is, however, `":"` on old Mac OS 9 systems.  Python has been around long enough that this used to be important.